# Are the cardinalities equal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

> Let $A$ be an uncountable set. Let $C$ be a countable set with $A\cap C = \emptyset$. Show that $|A\cup C| = |A|$.

Since $A$ is uncountable, it has an infinite countable subset, say $B$. Notice that $A \cup C = (A-B) \cup (B \cup C)$ and $(A-B)\cap (B \cup C) = \emptyset$. Since $B$ is an infinite countable set, $|B|=|\mathbb{N}|$. Since the union of countable sets is countable, and since $B$ is an infinite countable set, $B \cup C$ is an infinite countable set, so $|B \cup C|=|B| = |\mathbb{N}|$. Therefore, there exists a bijection $f:B\cup C \to B$. Define $h:A \cup C \to A$ by
\begin{align*}
    h(x) = 
    \begin{cases}
    f(x), & x \in B \cup C\\
    x, & x \in A - B.
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
From here I just need to show that $h$ is injective and surjective. Is this the right approach? Or am I missing any details?

Comment: This is a correct approach.

Comment: I don't think the general-topology tag is appropriate here -- maybe elementary-set-theory instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $|AUC| = |A|$, where $A$ is an uncountable set and $C$ is a countable set.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3713531/prove-that-auc-a-where-a-is-an-uncountable-set-and-c-is-a-countable)